# Converting pandas dataframe to desired dictionary of choice

Tags: python, json

I am new to converting pandas dataframe into json object.
I have a data frame:

[image: Description]

Expected json output after conversion is this.

```
{
  "Name": {
    "id": "Max",
  },
  "Favorites" : [
        {
            "id":"Apple",
            "priority":"High",
            "Count":"4"
        },
        {
            "id":"Oranges",
            "priority":"Medium",
            "Count":"2"
        },
        {
            "id":"Banana",
            "priority":"Low",
            "Count":"1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a freebie. Hope it helps you learn how to write it yourself in the future :)

```
output = []


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    entry = {
        "Name": {
            "id": row['Names']
        },
        "Favorites": [
            {
                "id": row['High_Priority_Goods_Name'],
                "priority": "High",
                "count": row['High_Priority_Goods_Count']
            },
            {
                "id": row['Medium_Priority_Goods_Name'],
                "priority": "Medium",
                "count": row['Medium_Priority_Goods_Count']
            },
            {
                "id": row['Low_Priority_Goods_Name'],
                "priority": "Low",
                "count": row['Low_Priority_Goods_Count']
            }
        ]
    }
    output.append(entry)

print(output)
```